# How to add controls from a control library to VS studio toolbox automatically (WP7)?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to achieve that when the user installs the WP7 control library he will find it in the Visual Studio toolbox automatically without manually adding it. In addition I would like to organize toolbox tabs in a logical manner.

I know it can be done for other platforms. For example I tried writing *.design.dll as described [here](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/justinangel/archive/2008/11/17/silverlight-design-time-extensibility.aspx) - it does not work for WP7.

Any pointers how to work with toolbox for VS 2010 / WP7?

Answer (score 1):

Nobody answered, so here is my brief summary:

1. The control library cannot be added to the Toolbox automatically unless you program VS plugin (package). Too much work for me...
2. *.design.dll (see the link above) basically works.

2a) You can hide controls from the Toolbox (BrowsableAttribute) and you can define control icons. That's probably everything you can do for Toolbox. The user has to add Toolbox tabs and "choose items" manually.

Well, I am not quite sure here, because when you drop the control dll file onto the Toolbox, then at least ToolboxTabNameAttribute works, i.e. corresponding Toolbox tabs are created automatically. Unfortunately, the tab is empty.

Also, when the control library is properly installed, then some of the controls are added to Choose items Toolbox dialog. Unfortunately, in my case most of the controls are missing and have to be added by manual browsing.

2b) Designer support (Properties window for the control) is better. You can hide properties (BrowsableAttribute), define categories (CategoryAttribute) and define descriptions (DescriptionAttribute).

Descriptions can be extracted from you documentation xml file, so that you don't need to write them again. To get the code google for MetadataBase.cs. Just be carefull, the files you'll find contain  fatal bugs (ParseDescription method) and ignore some properties (getters that return a collection).

After all, the result is not that bad.